# Jackson cannot deduce unique subtype in Spring Boot controller with 2 types sharing a common field

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have an interface called `Response` with a single field named `info`. This interface is implemented by two classes from different packages. Both the interface and the classes have the same name (if that is of importance). The first class contains only the `String info` field, while the second class has an additional field called `Integer number`.

```
package com.example;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(com.example.package1.Response.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(com.example.package2.Response.class)})
public interface Response {
    String getInfo();
}

///
com.example.package1;

public class Response implements com.example.Response {
    String info;
}

///
com.example.package2;

public class Response implements com.example.Response {
    String info;
    Integer number;
}
```

In my controller, I explicitly specify the usage of com.example.package1.Response

```
    @PostMapping
    fun start(
        @RequestBody response: com.example.package1.Response
    ): ResponseEntity<> {
        ///code here
    }
```

When pass a JSON object `{ "info": "info" }`, expecting Jackson to infer the mapping to this class. However, I encounter an exception:

```
Cannot deduce unique subtype of `com.example.package1.Response.class` (2 candidates match)]
```

How can I fix this that controller can map to correct type?